# How to check a subitem in ContextMenuStrip

Tags: c#, checked, contextmenustrip, subitem

```
(cms.Items[6] as ToolStripMenuItem).DropDownItems.Add("Close program",null, new EventHandler(CloseProgram_Click));
(cms.Items[6] as ToolStripMenuItem).DropDownItems.Add("Show message", null, new EventHandler(ShowMessage_Click));
(cms.Items[6] as ToolStripMenuItem).DropDownItems.Add("-");
(cms.Items[6] as ToolStripMenuItem).DropDownItems.Add("Do nothing", null, new EventHandler(DoNothing_Click));

private void CloseProgram_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // I want mark this menuItem on dropdownItem
}
```

When i choose menuItem, I want it be checked.

Like this.

[image: Like this.]

Comment: please upload the image to some other site, and give me the link in the comment, I will upload it to SO for you.

Answer (score 0):

Cast the parameter `sender` to `ToolStripMenuItem`, and then you can set its `Checked` property.

```
private void CloseProgram_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // I want mark this menuItem on dropdownItem
    ToolStripMenuItem menuitem = sender as ToolStripMenuItem;
        if (menuitem != null)
            menuitem.Checked = true;
}
```

you can get the `Checked` state of each menu item like this

```
bool ischecked = (programToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems[0] as ToolStripMenuItem).Checked;
```

Passing the correct index (0 for example), to get the menu item you want.

Comment: Tks, and how i can add a "tick" symbol to this?

Comment: i update my answer in response to you last (deleted) comment. but what do you mean by `tick symbol`?

Comment: https://www.google.com.vn/search?q=tick+symbol&client=firefox-a&hs=dLe&rls=org.mozilla:vi:official&channel=sb&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=Pax6VIqwCYv88QWit4DgBQ&ved=0CCgQsAQ

Comment: i c, you want a custom check mark. But customization is not easy in WinForm, unless the control has such property for you, maybe some 3rd party vendors like `DevExpress` provide such controls. Can't help you with this maybe you can search google with these keywords "winform menuitem custom check mark".